# How to extract and replace a String with specific format?

Tags: java, regex

I have input String like;

```
(rm01ADS21212, 'adfffddd', rmAdssssss, '1231232131', rm2321312322)
```

What I want to do is find all words starting with "rm" and replace them with remove function.

```
(remove(01ADS21212), 'adfffddd', remove(Adssssss), '1231232131', remove(2321312322))
```

I am trying to use replaceAll function but I don't know how to extract parts after "rm" literal.

```
statement.replaceAll("\\(rm*.,", "remove($1)");
```

Is there any way to get these parts?

Comment: You have not captured the substrings, thus `$1` is empty / null. Use something like `.replaceAll("\\brm\\w*", "remove($0)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Of course. I am getting exception "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1" but I don't know how to capture it.

Comment: What can be there after `rm` that needs to be matched? Just letters/digits? Do you also have any other restrictions? Like only match `rm...` inside parentheses?

Comment: "\\(rm*.," There shouldn't be a bracket here. This will not consider your second rm value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes only letters and digits like above until "," or ")"

Comment: `s.replaceAll("(rm(\\w+))", "remove($2)")` should work

Comment: @ernest_k yes it works perfectly can you create an anwer so I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not captured any substring with a *capturing group*, thus `$1` is `null`.

You may use

```
.replaceAll("\\brm(\\w*)", "remove($1)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3R9ODR/4)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (to start matching only at the start of a word)
- `rm`  - a literal part
- `(\w*)` - Group 1: 0+ word chars (letters, digits or underscores)

The `$1` in the replacement pattern stands for Group 1 value.

If you mean to match any chars other than a comma and whitespace after `rm`, use `"\\brm([^\\s,]*)"`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3R9ODR/3).

Comment: @hellzone It does now. Sorry, I was distracted by another user. I was still editing this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Use "Replace" with empty string .

Eg;

```
string str = "(rm01ADS21212, 'adfffddd', rmAdssssss, '1231232131', rm2321312322)";
 Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("rm", ""));
```

> Output : (01ADS21212, 'adfffddd', Adssssss, '1231232131', 2321312322)

Comment: Taking off 'rm' is not the expected output. Please read the question again.